# CSS horizontal alignment display-inline span

Tags: html, css

There is the following HTML code:

```
<div class="preloader">
  <img src="img/preloader.gif">
  <span>
    <strong>Получение адреса...</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.preloader span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I align span in div vertically, but now I need to align span horizontally. I've tried to use 'margin: 0 auto', but it doesn't work. Please tell me, how can I do it? Thanks! I need image with left alignment and text with center alignment as a result.

Comment: Can you show a mock up of the desired output?

Answer (score 8):

Use `text-align: center;`:

```css
.preloader {
  text-align: center;
}

.preloader img {
  float: left;
}

.preloader span {
  line-height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <img src="http://orig14.deviantart.net/f682/f/2010/331/4/e/darth_vader_icon_64x64_by_geo_almighty-d33pmvd.png">
  <span>
    <strong>Получение адреса...</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r0z75mey/4/

Comment: It align image too... I need that image is on the left

Comment: Text will be on the top, because image is floating. Past link for some real image and you'll see

Comment: But your text is center aligned horizontally, right? Cause that you were asking for...

Comment: But vertical alignment has been broken, I don't want it.

Comment: That's because you dont have a height on the span.

Comment: Add it please. Image has 64px height

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I added line-height of 64px to vertical align the span. I also added an updated fiddle to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```css
.preloader span {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.preloader {
  text-align: center;
}
.preloader img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <img src="img/preloader.gif">
  <span>
    <strong>Получение адреса...</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you check this link may be helpful for you 
                                                                                                               http://jsfiddle.net/allenktpr80/tq0ta3gs/

```
<div class="preloader">
  <img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/21.gif">
  <span>
    <strong>Please wait while its loading</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you that loader image to come in left of text then use this css

```
.preloader img {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/allenktpr80/qvxe7jo4/

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are able to change your html? If yes, please try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672395-loading-32.png">
  </div>
  <span>
    <strong>Получение адреса...</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.preloader {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 64px;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/utdwqs1v